# How to retrieve claim value of a user in wso2 apim

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am testing wso2 apim 4.0.0. I would like to send custom header to the backend. Lets say it as address which represents address of the user. This header should be retrieved from claim values of user. I was able to send username by creating custom sequence mediator and adding it to the Request Message Mediation. The contents of my sequence as follows:

```
<sequence name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> 
   <header name="user" expression="substring-before(get-property('api.ut.userId'), '@')" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

How can I retrieve address claim and send it to the backend as custom heaer in wso2 apim?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable 'Passing End User Attributes to the Backend'.

See:

- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/config-catalog/#jwt-configurations
- https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/#customizing-the-jwt-generation-completely